# Dynamically loading sound link with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get some dynamically loaded links to display via a javascript file and a JSON array(where links are contained).

Link1 is to another webpage, open in new tab is the hope.

Link2 is to a site hosting an mp3 of a sound. Hopefully get the sound to just play in this window, otherwise in a new tab.

My problem is I'm not too familiar with js syntax to know where I'm wrong.

The error is nothing happens: in the status bar at the bottom I see: "#http://etc.com" because of the # hash sign it doesn't show but I need the hash sign for the navigation/local links.

here is the link to what's on the server so you can see the big picture:
[wordExplorer](http://www.camelliakalra.com/499/portal/games/wordexplorer/)

Here is the code:

```
function SetAnchorProperties(aElemObj, classStr, hrefStr) {
  var aStr = arguments[3];
  if (aElemObj) {
    if ((classStr) && (hrefStr)) {
      aElemObj.setAttribute('class', classStr);
      if (hrefStr.search("http")) {
        (aElemObj.setAttribute('href', hrefStr));
      } else {
        (aElemObj.setAttribute('href', '#' + hrefStr));
      }
      console.log(classStr, hrefStr);
      console.log(hrefStr.search("http"));


    }
    if (aStr) {
      aElemObj.textContent = aStr;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks so much!!

Cam

Comment: What is your result with that code? Does it error? What's the problem?

Comment: nothing happens: in the status bar at the bottom I see: "#http://yaddayadda" because of the # hash sign it doesn't show but I need the hash sign for the navigation/local links.

Comment: Try editing your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve and where it fails. Also, if at all possible, create a jsFiddle so we can see the code in action and be able to pinpoint what went wrong. Right now, it still doesn't make sense what your question is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about jsFiddle, but there are like 8+ javascript files interlinked. Feel free to click the link about labeled as WordExplorer that takes you to the site itself.

Comment: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wf1woan3/) it's not showing properly though.

Comment: Great. Scale all that code down to **just** the parts that are causing the issue. That's still a whole lot of code to sort through.

Comment: Really can't figure out why jsFiddle won't work for my mess but feel free to look at the actual site: [wordExplorer link](http://www.camelliakalra.com/499/portal/games/wordexplorer/)